# Selenium C# File Upload Not Working With JavaScript Executor and SendKeys

Tags: c#, selenium

I am attempting to upload a file to the application using SendKeys to the `//input` tag and it won't enter into it, because style is `display:none`

I also attempted to execute a javascript where I set the attributes of style to `'visibility: visible; display: block;'`

This uploads the file, however, after few seconds the file disappears again. This happens when I interact with different element on the same page. I am not sure what is causing the file to disappear after. Any ideas?

Here is my selenium, C# code:

```
var el = Driver.Current.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='fileUpload']"));
var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.Current;
var script = "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: visible; display: block;')";
js.ExecuteScript(script, el);
//el.Clear();
el.SendKeys(@"PATH TO FILE");
```

Something to note, I have used different locators other than Xpath, I get the same results.

And here is my HTML:

[image]

And here how it looks in the app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you start interacting with other elements of the same page right after it is uploaded?
Give some time delay right after you upload. maybe use  Thread.Sleep(100). 
Also, to make sure it is uploaded correctly, try pressing enter right after you do el.SendKeys(@"PATH TO FILE"); maybe like this: el.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

Comment: I have added sleep for few seconds, but the file input goes away. It is a weird case. I have been using Windows Forms to actually open the file browser for now.